# Only show SUM value if it is negative

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design

I am summing the values in one column but I only want the query to show me the summed values if it is less than zero. How would I do this?

Comment: 1. Add a tag of your DBMS 2. Add an example of one case that it should show, and one it should not, the summed columns, so we may understand better your table names, and what exactly you want. Having a dynamic number of fields in the result set is kinda difficult and, I bet, not something you really need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say you have a table name your_table which have two columns

```
name  balance
A      -1
B      10
A      -5
```

Now According to your description output will be

```
 name balance
   A     -6
```

For this output query will be

```
select name,sum(balance)
  from your_table
  group by name
  having sum(balance)<0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `having` condition:

```
SELECT   grouping_col, SUM(num_col)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY grouping_col
HAVING   SUM(num_col) < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with case when

```
SELECT column1,SUM(case when numcolumn<0 then numcolumn else 0 end) as sumval
FROM mytable
group by column1
```